# ошибка при запуске Unity Recorder

Tags: unity3d

скачиваю Unity Recorder с  Asset Store  и он блокирует проигрывание сцены а в консоли 62 ошибки подскажите что нужно сделать

Comment: Этот ассет не работает с версиями 2019.2 и выше.

Comment: а какой рекодер работает?

Comment: Без понятия, я лишь объяснил вам, почему у вас не работает конкретно этот ассет.